# Extending Array with Subscript (Swift). Bug in Xcode 6 beta 7?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

Does somebody have an idea on why this code doesn't compile with Xcode 6 beta 7? It must be a very stupid mistake, or compiler's bug:

```
enum State : UInt8 {
    case Off = 0
    case On  = 1
}

extension Array {
    subscript (index: State) -> Element {
        get { 
            let i = Int(index.toRaw())
            return self[i] 
        }
        set { 
            let i = Int(index.toRaw())
            self[i] = newValue 
        }
    }
}

class MyClass  {
    var results = [0, 7]
    func getResult(#state: State) { 
        return results[state]  // Error here: State not convertible to Int ????
    }
}
```

I have tried using a Dictionary [State: Int] instead of Array [Int], and copiler gives also error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the return type in your `getResult` function:

```
func getResult(#state: State) -> Int {
```

Comment: Yeah... then the "stupid mistake" option wins. But Xcode doesn't seem to assess very well what is going on, though. The compiler should know that a function with no return type shouldn't try to return anything, right? Throwing "State not convertible to Int" is somehow misleading...

Comment: ... as almost any of the compiler error messages - when it doesn't make sense, usually it's a simple missing thing, or about incorrect usage of optionals

Comment: There's quite a few confusing or fairly generic error messages related to Swift code. I'm hoping that those will be cleaned up and improved by the time it's out of beta.